# can't open gltf file with three.js returns error with _onError for GLTFLoader.js and load for three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am starting with three.js and I am trying to open a glTF 3d model. I use Xampp as a local server and Firefox. The script himself has no problem in the console but it still doesn't work. The console returns:

```
error
​
bubbles: false
​
cancelBubble: false
​
cancelable: false
​
composed: false
​
currentTarget: null
​
defaultPrevented: false
​
eventPhase: 0
​
explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
isTrusted: true
​
lengthComputable: false
​
loaded: 0
​
originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
returnValue: true
​
srcElement: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
target: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
timeStamp: 121
​
total: 0
​
type: "error"
​
<get isTrusted()>: function isTrusted()
​
<prototype>: ProgressEventPrototype { lengthComputable: Getter, loaded: Getter, total: Getter, … }
GLTFLoader.js:89:14
    _onError http://localhost/3d/GLTFLoader.js:89
    load http://localhost/3d/three.js:26843
```

And here is my javascript script:

```
let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let test;

function init() {
  container = document.querySelector(".scene");

  //Create scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const fov = 35;
  const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 1000;

  //Camera setup
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 5, 30);

  const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
  light.position.set(50, 50, 100);
  scene.add(light);
  //Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //Load Model
  let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load("C:/xampp/htdocs/3d/test_3d.gltf", function(gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    test = gltf.scene.children[0];
    animate();
  });
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  test.rotation.z += 0.005;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

And here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Three.js Crash Course</title>
        <style>
            body {margin: 0;}
            canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="scene"></div>
        <script src='3d/three.js'></script>
        <script src='3d/GLTFLoader.js'></script>
        <script src='3d/3d.js' dever></script>
        <!--<script src='3d/jav.js'></script>-->
    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Try it with a relative URL instead of specifying an absolute file path to your local directory.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain me more precisely, what should I write and where. Thank you very much